# How to display a notification box onclick for all elements with href="#"?

Tags: javascript, notifications, onclick

I'd like to display an 'UNDER CONSTRUCTION' notification box on my website anytime a user clicks on an element with attribute `href="#"`.

I created a function which targets all elements with attribute `href="#"` onclick:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute('href') == '#')
    {
     allElements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}})
```

```html
<a href="#">Stuff</a><br>
<a href="#">More stuff</a>
<button>Btn</button>
```

Problem is, I need to target only the CLICKED elements.

Any approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e = e || window.event; /* Point to clicked element */
    var h = e.target; /* Get clicked element */
    if (h.getAttribute('href') == '#'){alert('woot')}})
```

```html
<a href="#">Stuff</a><br>
<a href="##">More stuff</a>
<button>Btn</button>
```

Comment: Yep, event delegation is a good idea - that way you only have to attach *one* listener, rather than a separate listener for every element. You might consider `.matches`: `if (e.target.matches('a[href="#"]')) /* do stuff */`